# Knime R snippet knime.out: 0 rows, n columns (with column names), node output: empty table, 0 rows and 0 columns

Tags: r, knime

If I have an R snippet node in Knime, which (under some circumstances) produces an empty dataframe as knime.out with some columns. E.g. dataframe called df with column names "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", issuing command

```
knime.out
```

produces output:

```
[1] Col1 Col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I would accept in this case that the R snippet node's Data Output would be an empty table with columns "Col1" and "Col2":

```
------------------------
| Row ID | Col1 | Col2 |
------------------------
```

But actually the Data Output is an empty table with no columns:

```
----------
| Row ID |
----------
```

My question is: is it an intended behavior of Knime (or I make some mistake), and if so, what could be the purpose of it?

With other words: why the structure of the R snippet's empty knime.out dataframe differs from the empty Data Output table of the R snippet Knime node?

Comment: Without knime, was it supposed to be an empty dataframe?

Comment: Normally it's not an empty dataframe, but sometimes it is (as I said: "under some circumstances"). My problem is not the empty dataframe in the R Snippet, but the different structure of the empty dataframe in R Snippet and the resulting empty table in Knime (with vs without columns). I can handle the consequences of this behavior, but I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Great, just wanted to clarify this is not an R issue, but only how knime outputs the results.

Comment: OK, I have added some clarification to the question ("With other words: why the structure of the R snippet's empty knime.out dataframe differs from the empty Data Output table of the R snippet Knime node?").